# Use an if statement to filter for smallest/biggest value R

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

below is an example of part of a df I'm trying to filter

```
Gene                Chr     Start       End         V5  Strand
ENSMUSG00000028364  chr4    64012669    64020725    .   -   
ENSMUSG00000028364  chr4    63959785    64047015    .   -
ENSMUSG00000018387  chr11   53457249    53467501    .   +   
ENSMUSG00000018387  chr11   53457205    53467766    .   +
```

For each gene I'd like to keep the row with the first (or last) values in cols 3 and 4 depending which strand the gene is on. I've tried a few different things, but both are giving out errors and not working

```
df <- df %>%
   group_by(Gene) %>%
   ifelse(df$Strand == "+", (filter(Start==first(Start), End ==first(End))), (filter(End==last(End), Start ==last(Start))))

Error in ifelse(., df$Strand == "+", (filter(Start == first(Start),  : unused argument ((filter(End == last(End), Start == last(Start))))


df <- df %>%
   group_by(Gene) %>%
   {if (df$Strand == "+") filter(Start==first(Start), End ==first(End)) else filter(End==last(End), Start ==last(Start))}

Error in filter(Start == first(Start), End == first(End)) : object 'Start' not found
In addition: Warning message:
In if (df$Strand == "+") filter(Start == first(Start),  :

 Error in filter(Start == first(Start), End == first(End)) : object 'Start' not found
```

This is what I'd like after filtering, for each gene if the strand is + keep the entire row with the smallest start and end co-ords (initially filter on start, then on end), and if the strand is negative, keep the rows with the largest start and end co-ords (first filter on end coord, followed by start).

```
Gene                Chr     Start       End         V5  Strand  
ENSMUSG00000028364  chr4    63959785    64047015    .   -
ENSMUSG00000018387  chr11   53457249    53467501    .   +
```

Any suggestions to get this work please? Thanks!

Comment: I think you need `filter` alone and not an `ifelse`. What is your expected output(a bit unclear to me)?

Comment: Seems you need this but not sure: `df %>% 
  group_by(Gene) %>% 
  filter(ifelse(Strand=="+", first(Start) & first(End), last(Start) & last(End)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this using `filter`.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  group_by(Gene) %>%
  # Get first row for "+" and last for "-"
  filter(Strand == "+" & row_number() == 1 | Strand == "-" & row_number() == n())
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this a problem to keep the first values of `Start` and `End` when `Strand == '+'`?

The code below filters by `Strand` before grouping, in order to get rid of unnecessary data. Then it groups and summarises.

If you do not need all the original columns but only want to keep the grouping column `Gene` and the summary columns `Start` and `End`, remove the `left_join`, it's there to get the rest of the input data set columns.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  filter(Strand == '+') %>%
  group_by(Gene) %>%
  summarise(Start = first(Start), End = first(End)) %>%
  left_join(df)
#Joining, by = c("Gene", "Start", "End")
## A tibble: 1 x 6
#  Gene                  Start      End Chr   V5    Strand
#  <chr>                 <int>    <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> 
#1 ENSMUSG00000018387 53457249 53467501 chr11 .     +
```